# file movement from one directory to another

Tags: informix, 4gl

i have a variable that holds the file name and the location of that file, i need to move that file from one location to another.How can it be done using informix 4gl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RUN command will be used:

```
LET cmd = "mv ", old_location, "/", file_name, " ", new_location

RUN cmd
```

This assumes that `old_location`, `file_name` and `new_location` are all VARCHAR variables and not CHAR variables.  If they are CHAR, you need to strip trailing blanks before concatenating:

```
LET cmd = "mv ", old_location CLIPPED, "/", file_name CLIPPED, " ", new_location CLIPPED
```

(You could omit the last CLIPPED.)  This also assumes there are no spaces in the file names or locations.  You have to work a bit harder if spaces can be present; you have to work considerably harder if you need to deal with quotes or newlines (etc) in the file names.